# Adding single sign on to a Ruby on Rails application on Bluemix

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

How can I add the single sign on service to a Ruby on Rails application I created on Bluemix?

When I read the documentation on Bluemix (at https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/SingleSignOn/index.html#sso_gettingstarted) the second step specifies to "Create a Liberty for Java app or a Node.js app". This leads me to think that I can only add the SSO service to a Liberty for Java or a Node.js app, but I can not use it for my already working application (which is a Ruby on Rails app).

Answer (score 0):

You're right. As reported in the [Docs](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/SingleSignOn/index.html#sso_gettingstarted) page you mentioned, currently the only two runtimes that are compatible with the SSO service are Liberty for Java and Node.js. This means that those two runtimes are fully supported. However I've seen some Ruby applications using the SSO service in the past. You could take a look at [bluemix-sso-sample](https://github.com/tbeauvais/bluemix-sso-sample) on Github: that's a Sinatra application but I think you can find useful information to try to integrate your RoR application too.

Comment: I tried to install the sample, following the instructions. I ran the following without problem:                                                                                     git clone https://github.com/tbeauvais/bluemix-sso-sample.git
cd bluemix-sso-sample
bundle                     But when I tried to run:

Comment: rspec spec  I'm getting the error: unexpected ':', expecting ')' (SyntaxError), something is wrong and I couldn't figure it out yet